# jQuery select a href with specific word inside

Tags: jquery

i try to change a jQuery Code. I need to change a Code Line to something, that select all a href link who has my site url inside AND not a word "visit" in link.

the following Code ist the standard Code from the Plugin and i want to change it.

lets take a look on the url.

https://www.example.com

the jQuery select all a href because my site url is inside example, but i have external links, which should be not selected.

external Link https://www.example.com/visit/1234

i tried (add :not.a[href*="visit] to https line

```
jQuery('a[href^="http://'+document.domain+'"],a[href^="https://'+document.domain+'"]:not.a[href*="visit],a[href^="/"],a[href^="?"]').each(function()
```

full code (123 instead of plugin name)

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['123_123'])) { ?>
            function 123_add_link() {
                jQuery('a[href^="http://'+document.domain+'"],a[href^="https://'+document.domain+'"],a[href^="/"],a[href^="?"]').each(function() {
                    this.href += (/\?/.test(this.href) ? '&' : '?') + '123=true&123_123=true';
                });
            }
            jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(123_add_link());
            jQuery(document).ready(123_add_link());
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter all matching selectors by using the [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method instead of the [`:not` pseudoselector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```js
$('a[href^="https://www.example.com"],a[href^="http://www.example.com"]')
    .not('[href*="/visit/"]')
    .css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.example.com/1234">Internal</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/visit/123">External 1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/visit/1234">External 2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/1234">Internal</a>
<a href="https://www.example2.com/visit/1234">Hotlink</a>
```